# How to post a list with django-restframework testclient

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am writing unit-tests for my api views. Right now I'm facing the problem that I cannot post lists using the `testclient` provided by `django-restframwork`:

My view looks like this:

```
@detail_route(methods=['post'])
def dosomestuff(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    watchlist = request.data.get('watchlist', [])
    sortedoutlist = request.data.get('sortedoutlist', [])
    # create some objects
    ...

    return Response('success'), status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The json objects I post to this endpoint normally look like this:

```
{"watchlist": [32, 12, 23], "sortedoutlist": [1, 2,3 ]}
```

Now I set up a testcase for this view:

```
class MyTestCase(APITestCase):

    def test_dosomestuff(self):
        url = reverse('dosomestuff')
        data = {'watchlist': [32, 12, 23],
                'sortedoutlist': [1, 2,3 ]}
        r = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The problem is that the `watchlist` and `sortedoutlist` recieved in the view are no `lists`, but `int` containing the last value of the sent list (watchlist is 23 and sortedoutlist is 3.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I post lists in the testcase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default format for `Client.post` is multipart. You need to specify `json` using the [`format` parameter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#making-requests):

```
r = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped.